# Сжатие JPG для Google PageSpeed

Tags: jpeg, сжатие, google-page-speed

Интересная штука: Google PageSpeed Insights показывает что на сайте (почти на любом) есть неоптимизированные изображения, которые можно уменьшить например, вот так (скопировал из отчета, опустив URL картинок):

- на 39,3 КБ (50 %).
- на 38 КБ (44 %).
- на 33,7 КБ (44 %).

Далее, я беру и загружаю эту картинку с сайта, закачиваю на свой VPS, выполняю команды сжатия JPG без потерь инструментами jpegtran и jpegoptim (пробовал оба, оба [рекомендуются Гуглом](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeImages)):

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile min.img.jpg img.jpg

jpegoptim --strip-all img.jpg
```

Но оба сжимают JPG максимум на пару процентов. Большего можно добиться, только если указывать качество, но тогда картинки сильно ухудшаются в качестве. Как же тогда гугл показывает что возможно сжатие на 50%, если у меня всего на 2%?

Comment: Предположу, что он подразумевает именно ухудшение качества)

Comment: Согласен, можно так предположить, но фот фраза из той же страницы:
Существуют инструменты, выполняющие **дополнительное сжатие файлов JPEG и PNG без потерь и снижения качества**. Для файлов JPEG рекомендуется использовать jpegtran или jpegoptim (доступно только для Linux, выполнять с параметром --strip-all)

Comment: Кстати как вариант - использовать `2x` изображения хренового качества? Гуглу наверное дорого кэшировать и наказывает)

Comment: В конце страницы с проверкой Гугл предлагает скачать архив с им же сжатыми картинками. Если качество неважно, можно ими заменить те, что на сайте.

Comment: Судя по скачанным после проверки сайта картинкам в архиве, Google сжимает их с качеством примерно 85%, может чуть ниже.
В итоге, команда обработки такая:
jpegoptim --max=85 --strip-all img.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Малая степень сжатия. Ключ quality добавьте.

Comment: Да, я уже понимаю что именно в этом дело.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно долго занимался этим вопросом для себя. Выяснил, что PageSpeed не ругается на jpeg и png если:

1. Они сжаты в Photoshop для веб с качеством 50%.
2. Не содержат никакой служебной информации вроде копирайта.

Что удивительно, качество нормальное. Сжатые таким образом картинки визуально практически невозможно отличить от несжатых. Размещал такие картинки на сайтах весьма требовательных клиентов, нареканий не было.

Про jpegtran ничего не могу сказать, не пробовал.

Comment: 50 фотошопное это отвратное качество совсем. Так жать только для 2x можно. Да и после фотошопа ещё 2% сверху сжать можно

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev нравится вам это качество или нет - неважно. Важно то, что PageSpeed ругается на картинки, сжатые с 60%.

Comment: меня дизайнер бы прибил за такую оптимизацию. взять и убить качество выход только для говносайтов

Comment: То что не ругается факт интересный. Но я в jpegoptim ставлю качество 85, и при разглядывании даже без увеличения очень заметно ухудшение качества. Поэтому 50 это вообще не дело.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev значит, PageSpeed требует качества для говносайтов. Мы тут что обсуждаем? Как жать для каких сайтов или требования PageSpeed? В Google напишите.

Comment: @Denis проведем эксперимент. Была исходная картинка 5000x2815. Скачал, изменил размер в шопе на 1920x1281. Сохранил с 50% качеством. Открыл исходник заново, изменил размер, увеличил канву, добавил вторым слоем сжатое на 50%, поставил их рядом. Сохранил как jpeg с макс качеством 12. Залил на диск: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/6SArGLGuz8VnXEyroWY7x18WhG_tzvkkgtk0bQNtRypntltVFUYzbaVer3fOPBHhWqMkc7CR=w1920-h1070-rw   теперь скажите - где исходное изображение и где сжатое на 50%?

Comment: @KAGGDesign ошибка 403

Comment: @andreymal забыл доступ открыть https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/SNsEW3fsP7fymOPdGPjUtWuocNd4MN-Udj1OB2SRVbkKAJM_oIdDDZn1n56_Mk7R_Cv29BP52Lu-F4Y=w1920-h1070-rw

Comment: @KAGGDesign всё равно 403

Comment: @andreymal не пускает по прямой ссылке, вот оно что. вот так: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9hcUkIAYjaFVnIxTzFkaE1TYlU/view